# What exactly does "Allow Everything" do in magento adminhtml xml?

Tags: xml, magento

Can anyone tell me what the title node of the xml below actually does? I am having a tough time finding relevant information.

```
<config>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <tag_manager translate="title" module="googletagmanager">
                                    <title>Google Tag Manager</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </tag_manager>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag is used to generate the `All` option in the user role definition.
It's useful in the core file but has no value in the custom modules. I honestly don't know how this got out of hand. Everywhere on the web there are extensions and code samples that have this `all` tag. Maybe it's just an other case of *This is how they do it* just like using `$installer = $this` in upgrade scripts. You can remove it and see what happens...nothing.